# How do i find formula for the recurrence relation :$x_{n+1}= x^2_{n}-x^2_{n-1}$ with :$x_{-1}=0,x_{0}=\frac{3}{4}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, roots

How do i find formula for the recurrence relation  according to the below

initial conditions:

$x_{n+1}= x^2_{n}-x^2_{n-1}$ with :=$x_{-1}=0,x_{0}=\frac{3}{4}$ ?

Note:$n=0,1,2\cdots$

Thank you for any help

Comment: Have you computed the first terms ?

Comment: Are you trying to take a limit? I don't know what you mean by "solve this equation."

Comment: it is a difference equation with initial conditions want to get the solutions and in this case  there is a convergence of dynamics and boundedness of solution

Comment: But what do you mean by "solutions"? Are you looking for a closed form expression of the terms of the recurrence?

Comment: yes, example when we get a solution we can example using it to compute x_10 ,...

Comment: pleas check this pdf and look what i meant by solution with given initial conditions and look to page 08 ,question 2:http://de2de.synechism.org/c1/sec14.pdf

Comment: With nonlinear recurrence relations, a closed-form solution is by far more the exception than the rule. For example, one hardly would expect to find a closed-form solution for the logistic map $x_{n+1}=r x_n(1-x_n)$ with its well-known chaotic behavior / period-doubling bifurcations.

Comment: do  you meant then, only numerical computation  ?

Comment: @Semiclassical, does it solutions oscillates for some iteration of dynamics ?

Comment: As said by others, finding a formula for $x_n$ is impossible and showing that $x_n\to0$ is direct.